# How does d3.csv function type works?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm watching a tutorial on D3.js and I cannot understand how the d3.csv function is working.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", type, function (myArrayOfObjects){
    myArrayOfObjects.forEach(function (d){
      console.log(d.x + d.y);
    });
  });

 function type(d){
   d.x = parseFloat(d.x);
   d.y = parseFloat(d.y);
   return d;
  }
```

data.csv is containing this values

```
x,y
100,100
130,120
80,180
180,80
180,40
```

The function is working correctly, printing on console the correct values but i can't understand how the call to the *type* function works. 
I thought *type* function was called once for each element in the CSV file but then, after inserting console.log statement i noticed it is called just once. How does it take all data and not just the first pair of elements?

Thank you

EDIT:
This is the result:

```
200
250
260
260
220
```

Is the function called just once or once for each element in the csv?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: What is the exact console output? The way it is now, the first snippet should print `200.0, 250.0, 260.0, 260.0, 220.0`.

Comment: @Stefano I updated my answer to reflect your edit to the question.

Comment: Putting console.log into the type function should answer your question, I'd imagine.

Comment: I am utterly confused! It works as expected printing five values (the sum per row), the `type` function works just fine, or else the log would print `”100100”, “130120”, “80180”...`. So, what is your question?

Comment: @altocumulus it works fine, prints the desired values. I just wanted why the function *type* was called just once, as i noticed from putting console.log as first statement of each func.

Comment: @Stefano Why are you saying that the row function is called just once? It's not the case: https://jsfiddle.net/8bbgtu5b/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i can't make it work. By my test the function type is just called once (tested with console.log() statement inside the function)

Comment: Please, **share** this test! Everybody is saying that we can't reproduce the behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#csv), `d3.csv` works by calling the second argument is what is essentially a map function. It states that your example is equivalent to:

```
d3.request("data.csv")
    .mimeType("text/csv")
    .response(function(xhr) { return d3.csvParse(xhr.responseText, type); })
    .get(callback);
```

[How d3 delimited works.](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parseRows) This is the doc space that is the underlying code for the `csvParse`.

```
dsv.parseRows(string[, row])
```

Is the example where it is stated that `In effect, row is similar to applying a map and filter operator to the returned rows.`

I created a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2fta9x0/10/) which demonstrates, you're situation, but does not replicate the issue.

**UPDATE**

To answer the updated question: the function is called once per line, as per above.

Comment: I'm curious to why this was downvoted and how I could improve on my answer?

Comment: It wasn’t me, but I suppose, it’s because your assumption is wrong. It is called a **row** conversion function, because it is called for every single row.

Comment: I removed the last line which is where I stated it is only called once, slightly more accurate now I guess.

Comment: But, how does it fit OP’s observations that it is called only once? I think we haven’t seen the full picture yet and this is either not reproducible or a misconception.

Comment: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Ya according to the MDN Docs it should be called for every instance.